# how to uncheck checkboxes when another is checked?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

im kinda trying to get into programming in general and was wondering how to uncheck / check with updating the array-

like as soon as someone checks a 2nd checkbox it should uncheck the first option and update the search (w the new data)- im a mere beginner and kinda lost rn so would appreciate any form of help

```
<form action="index.php" id="form1" name="form1" method="get">
    <?php $i = 0; foreach ($row_page_nav_kategorie as $row_page_nav_kategorie) { ?>
        <label class="checkbox-container">
            <input <?php if (strpos($url,$row_page_nav_kategorie['typ']) == true) {echo 'checked="checked"';}?> 
                type="checkbox" 
                class="checkmark" 
                name="hotelKategorie[]" 
                id="ckb5"
                value="<?php echo $row_page_nav_kategorie['typ']; ?>"
                onclick="kategorie(<?php echo $i ?>);" 
                onchange="submit()"/>
            <?php echo $row_page_nav_kategorie['typ']; $i++;?>
        </label>
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: you need some javascript/jquery to achieve this. or use radio button.

Comment: if you want some checkboxes to be selected only once of them, you should use radio buttons, and for the 'update the search if change' you will need some JS

Comment: as a note: never use inline-js. It's a bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code, you should also not mix JS and PHP as they're executed differently and can result in unexpected behaviour

Comment: Use radio buttons for this: It will lead to a better user experience. Users understand radio buttons clear out other choices when clicked, and multiple checkboxes can be checked.

Answer (score 5):

You should use radio buttons, but if you want to overwrite checkbox functionality below code will take care of it, I have added a common class on your inputs:

```
function checkboxClick(obj) {
    var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("checkkbox-option");
    for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
        cbs[i].checked = false;
    }
    obj.checked = true;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4o1t75xs/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all welcome to the community!

As for your question, there is multiple ways to handle this, one of wich is as followed:

In HTML there's an attribute called `radio` wich you can add to your input by using `type='radio'`. In a set of radio buttons, only one can be checked at any time. If you then want to immedietely submit your form, you can use something like `onChange='this.form.submit()'`. This will submit your form when the value is changed, such as pressing on a different radio button.

Something to keep note of is that the attribute `onChange` is case sensitive as far as i'm aware. You were heading in the right direction with `onchange="submit()`, but your code doesn't know what to submit. `this.form.submit()` will submit the form that the element is in.

Answer (score 0):

Use Radio Buttons or use JavaScript on your page to dynamically uncheck other checkboxes when you click on one.

If you want to dynamically update the page content with the new search results you should also look into AJAX which basically means you will call PHP functions from JavaScript code and those will return JSON arrays that you can exploit to modify your page's DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try THIS

HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check1" class="checkbox" /> CheckBox1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check2" class="checkbox" /> CheckBox2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check3" class="checkbox" /> CheckBox3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="check4" class="checkbox" /> CheckBox4</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

if you want to uncheck the selected checkbox

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    $(".checkbox").not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

hope this helps, thanks !!!